# SPSS gets me ' Set to system missing due to overflow'

Tags: spss

I am generating a multivariable regression analysis from the Generalized Linear Model tab in SPPS for a binomial dependent outcome variable (mortality). I included several factors and covariates in the model.

However, for some reason the factor ASA (coded as 1, 2, 3 or 4) gives a specific comment in the generated table: 'Set to system missing due to overflow'. Although I could generally ignore it and use the adjusted p-value and confidence intervals for the odds ratios, it gives me problems when I try to generate estimated marginal means from the model; these become rather low. If I omit ASA from the model, the estimated marginal means become better, although it does have impact on the significance and confidence intervals.

I have tried recoding ASA into ASA1, ASA2, ASA3 and ASA4 and running the model again with these 4 variables instead of only ASA. These gave the identical outcomes and problem.

I hope it may be something arbitrary. Is there anyone who had a likewise problem and what would be the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps if you add to your post a reproducible example (data + code) someone can come up with a diagnosis and a solution. As it is, with no additional information it's really impossible for us to guess what is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Hello Eli, unfortunately I can not share my datafile itself due to data ownership. 

So what I am doing is adding 6 variables in a GLM. With mortality (1/0) as a dependent variable. Age and BMI are included as covariates, ASA score (1/2/3/4), high volume expert status (0/1), CRLM or HCC status in case of malignancy (0/1/2) and difficulty score (1/2/3) as factors. 

Only addition of ASA score gives me the problems with the estimated marginals means (low values). And probably before that, with the model itself (extreme values). 

Maybe indeed some collinearity problem, as suggested below.

Comment: What is being set to 0? Is it one or more B coefficients, or Exp(B) values? Is there a warning earlier in the output about complete or quasi-complete separation?